# PHP MySQL / WordPress Function / Ninja Forms

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am trying to populate a drop down list of supplier names with a WordPress plugin "Ninja Forms" using a query to a external database connection and custom code in functions.php.

The drop down list on the form appears to be populating with the correct quantity of results (i.e. 800+ items) but instead showing [object Object] instead of the suppliers name.

The code below is where I got up to, any support on adding the queried supplier name (SUP_Name) instead of [object Object] would be of great use.

```
add_filter('ninja_forms_render_options','my_pre_population_callback', 10, 2);
function my_pre_population_callback($options, $settings) {

if( $settings['key'] == 'supplier_list' ) {

$connection = mysqli_connect( "IP:port", "username", "password", "db" );
if (!$connection) {  die('Not connected : ' . mysqli_error());}

$db_selected = mysqli_select_db($connection,"db");
if (!$db_selected) {
die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mysqli_error());
}

$query = "SELECT SUP_Name FROM db.sup_supplier";
$results = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
if (!$results) {
die('Invalid query: ' . mysqli_error());
}

$options = array(); 
$options[] = array("label" => "Select the supplier", "value" => "");
foreach ($results as $result) {
$options[] = array("label" => $result, "value" => $result);
}

wp_reset_postdata();
}

return $options;
mysqli_close($con);
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `[object object]` sounds like a JS issue. Unrelated but `mysqli_select_db` is not needed, you selected your DB in the connection (parameter 4).

Comment: [mysqli_query](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) returns a [mysqli_result](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php) object. You need to iterate through the result with a fetch function. See the mysqli_result page for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to achieve what I am after with the following

```
$options = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results))
{
$options[] = array (
'label' => $row['SUP_Name'],
'value' => $row['SUP_Name'] );
}
```